# How to go from TextureImporterFormat to TextureFormat?

Tags: c#, import, unity-game-engine, compression, textures

It's a Unity3d specific question, but I thought I'd ask it here since I get no usefull feedback in the Unity forums.

In short; I need to get the corresponding `TextureFormat` for any `TextureImporterFormat`.

I'm writing an `AssetPostprocessor`; I want to alter textures after they're imported, and then I want to compress them.

So in the `OnPostprocessTexture(Texture2D texture)` function I want to compress the texture in the textureformat defined in the editor (in the `TextureImporter`), like it would if I didn't do anything in this function.

However, the compression function (`EditorUtility.CompressTexture()`) expects the format to be of type `TextureFormat`, but the only format I can get is of type `TextureImporterFormat`.

How do I get from the one to the other?

Or how can I avoid this problem alltogether?

I'm doing it manually now, which is a pain the ass. especially since it differs depending on the version of Unity, which also means it could change with any new Unity update. :(

Comment: why the thumbs down?

Comment: Please don't overuse **bold** formatting, especially for `code`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to overuse it, I just wanted the keywords to stand out to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this question, kinda late but thought I should answer it anyway.

Turns out I was misinterpreting the results I got. 
Compression happens automatically after this function.

I had made a test to see if textures where being compressed after using OnPostprocessTexture(), and thought they weren't, but they are.